# nginx rewrite file location

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, directory, lighttpd

In my application, I am trying to link `http://domain.com/accounts/login` and `/accounts/register` to `http://domain.com/accounts.php?action=$` where `$` is this: `http://domain.com/accounts/$`

I don't know where to define the rewrite and what to put down.

I have access to the entire VPS via SSH, but I'm not sure what file to edit. So where is the file located?

I checked the /opt/ folder, it appears to be empty. I might be running lighttpd, so can you help me out for both instances? Otherwise, can you tell me how to check whether I use lighttpd.

Comment: Oh, the file will be in your `conf` directory, wherever your Nginx installation is. If you can't find it, try a `find / -name nginx`.

Comment: Thanks, my specific domain nginx conf was in /etc/nginx/enabled-sites/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rewrite /accounts/(login|register) /accounts.php?action=$1
```

should do the trick. Put it inside your `server` (or `location`) directive.